# How do I integrate paypal adaptive payment with cake php 1.3 version?

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

I have a application in Cakephp 1.3 where I need to integrate latest paypal adaptive payment system. I get code sample from paypal web site for adaptive payment. I get code here https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments after login. It provide me a rest API SDK where I get code for pay with credit card.

```
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php'; 
use PayPal\Api\Address; 
use PayPal\Api\Amount; 
use PayPal\Api\CreditCard; 
use PayPal\Api\Payer; 
use PayPal\Api\Payment; 
use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument; 
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

$addr = new Address(); 
$addr->setLine1("3909 Witmer Road"); 
$addr->setLine2("Niagara Falls"); 
$addr->setCity("Niagara Falls"); 
$addr->setState("NY"); 
$addr->setPostal_code("14305"); 
$addr->setCountry_code("US"); 
$addr->setPhone("716-298-1822");

$card = new CreditCard(); 
$card->setType("visa"); 
$card->setNumber("4417119669820331"); 
$card->setExpire_month("11"); 
$card->setExpire_year("2019"); 
$card->setCvv2("012"); 
$card->setFirst_name("Joe"); 
$card->setLast_name("Shopper"); 
$card->setBilling_address($addr);

$fi = new FundingInstrument(); 
$fi->setCredit_card($card);

$payer = new Payer(); 
    $payer->setPayment_method("credit_card");
$payer->setFunding_instruments(array($fi));

$amount = new Amount(); 
$amount->setCurrency("USD"); 
$amount->setTotal("1.00");

$transaction = new Transaction(); 
$transaction->setAmount($amount); 
$transaction->setDescription("This is the payment description.");

$payment = new Payment(); 
$payment->setIntent("sale"); 
$payment->setPayer($payer); 
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

try { 
  $payment->create($apiContext); 
} 
catch (\PPConnectionException $ex) 
{ echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL; var_dump($ex->getData()); 
exit(1); }
```

Is there any other easy way do implement adaptive payment with paypal in Cakephp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code sample you provided from the REST SDK? You shouldn't be using that if you're trying to use Adaptive Payments. Adaptive Payments doesn't have a direct credit card payment option and that is what the code sample you provided is trying to do.

Here is a direct link to the PHP SDK for Adaptive Payments:
https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php